# Breaking a program with try, catch

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a function `t()`. If i encounter any error while trying to get the value of `a=t()`. I want to break the loop and don't display any errors.

Mostly I get `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered` or `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars`.

I tried the following but the loop don't break.

```
for i in range(100):
    try:
       a=t(i)
    except:
       print('breaking')
       break
```

Comment: [Are you sure you know what `break` does?](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: What do you mean by "the program don't break"? What behavior do you observe, and how does it differ from what you expect? Do you realize that `print('breaking')` will never run, since you put it *after* the `break`?

Comment: Sorry I want to exit the loop

Comment: Warnings aren't something you catch with try-except. They go through a different mechanism. They aren't considered errors, just "hey, you might want to check this out".

Comment: Your `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered` is not a Python native error. The native Python error for divide by zero would be `ZeroDivisionError: [float or integer type]`. Something in `t()` is catching the divide by zero error and turning that into console message. Just redirect stderr...

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an error on warnings if you want.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')

try:
    for x in range(0,5):
        do_something()
        warnings.warn(Warning()) # Trigger a warning to test
except:
    print "Broke"
```

Comment: Yeah it's running inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pass` if you don't want anything to be done with the exception.
For example:

```
for i in reversed(range(100)):
    try:
        print 3/i
    except:
        pass
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using except: RuntimeError if this is the only error that occurs.

```
for i in range(100):
try:
    a=t(i)
except RuntimeError:
    print('breaking')
    #then continue your code here for the exception
```